# Update d3 body text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How do I best update a body text element from a SVG tree node mouseover event?  When I try the following the text is updated, but the SVG is removed from the display.  Here is a the code:

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('text').text('The Entry Point and M Code: ')
  .attr('class', 'centralText')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 10)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

  .append('svg')
```

here is my event code:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', node_class)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + source.x0 + ',' + source.y0 + ')'; })
    .style('cursor', function(d) {
      return (d.children || d._children) ? 'pointer' : '';})
    .on('click', click)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         d3.select('body')
            .text('M Code: is this')
```

Comment: your last line replaces the whole `body` with a single line of text. So the svg is also erased

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues that are coming up. First, your initialization of `svg` is appending it to a `text` element, which is a bad idea. Second, to update the text you're replacing the body text and not the text element.

Two changes need to be made. First, change your `mouseover` function to this:

```
 d3.select('body').select('text')
            .text('M Code: is this');
```

This would normally fix it, but the second problem is that the `svg` is appended to the `text` element so it will still be erased. To fix this, change your declaration to the following:

```
d3.select('body')
  .append('text').text('The Entry Point and M Code: ')
  .attr('class', 'centralText')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 10)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

 var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
```